# Parse Exception

Tags: maven, jaxb

I have the same element id in two different complex types of an xml, I am getting the below exception if i try to parse using maven Jaxb plugin ,Is there a way to parse without renaming using the elements with the help of  bindings  , As i have the attribute id atleast 30 times in the schema.Thanks in advance

com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: Property "Id" is already defined. Use <jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.

```
            <xs:element name="aliases" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="alias" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element ref="tran" minOccurs="0"/>
                                    <xs:element name="id">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:simpleContent>
                                                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                                    <xs:attribute name="old_value" type="xs:string"/>
                                                </xs:extension>
                                            </xs:simpleContent>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                                <xs:attribute name="end" type="xs:string"/>
                                <xs:attribute name="start" type="xs:string"/>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>



<xs:element name="tin_affiliation">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="tran" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="id">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                            <xs:attribute name="old_value" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="end" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="start" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution to using a binding file is to declare the ID Type separately. Since it looks identical in both elements, and since the conflict in this case is due to a duplicate type declaration.

The Schema would then look like the following.

**Note:** It's tested and working, but had to comment `<xs:element ref="tran" minOccurs="0"/>` since I don't have the definition.

### Schema

```xml
<xs:element name="aliases">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="alias" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <!--<xs:element ref="tran" minOccurs="0"/> -->
                        <xs:element name="id" type="idType" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:attribute name="end" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="start" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="tin_affiliation">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <!-- <xs:element ref="tran" minOccurs="0"/> -->
            <xs:element name="id" type="idType" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="end" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="start" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="idType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            <xs:attribute name="old_value" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

### Generated Java Class: IdType

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "idType", propOrder = {
    "value"
})
public class IdType {

    @XmlValue
    protected String value;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "old_value")
    protected String oldValue;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the value property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the value property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the oldValue property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getOldValue() {
        return oldValue;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the oldValue property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setOldValue(String value) {
        this.oldValue = value;
    }

}
```

### Generated Java Class: TinAffiliation

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "id"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "tin_affiliation")
public class TinAffiliation {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected IdType id;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "end")
    protected String end;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "start")
    protected String start;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the id property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link IdType }
     *     
     */
    public IdType getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the id property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link IdType }
     *     
     */
    public void setId(IdType value) {
        this.id = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the end property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getEnd() {
        return end;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the end property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setEnd(String value) {
        this.end = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the start property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the start property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setStart(String value) {
        this.start = value;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple XML attibutes/elements with same name in your XML element without any issues.  The exception you are seeing is when this would result in a generated class having two properties with the same name.  This can occur in the following situations.

1. A complex type contains an attribute and element with the same name.
2. A complex type contains an attribute/element with the same name as an attribute/element as a complex type that it extends.

Comment: Thanks a lot Doughan , it is because of the reason 1 as mentioned by you. Is there a way i can rename the attribute id wherever it occurs in the XSD to different name say idAttribute.

Comment: I want to rename the attributes identifier in the generated pojo ,I understand we can achieve t by using the bindings individually,
Is there a way I can do it by replacing  recursively in all the complex type wherever it conflicts  Or  Rename a particular attribute wherever it occurs in an Schema without mentioning the complex type.
        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name=MYComplexType]">
            <bindings node=".//xs:attribute[@name=abc]">
                <property name="abcAttribute"/>
            </bindings>
        </bindings>

Answer (score 0):

I Could able to achieve this using the plugins  org.codehaus.mojo: jaxb2-maven-plugin: 2.3 and   org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-annotate:0.6.4 and with the below binding configuration notably multiple="true

```
<jxb:bindings node=".//xs:attribute[@name='abc]"
                multiple="true">
                <jxb:property name="abc_attribute" />
            </jxb:bindings>
        </jxb:bindings>
```